# How can I avoid LGHT0306 when adding a very large file to a WiX Burn bootstrapper?

Tags: wix, burn, wix3.9

I am using [WiX](http://wixtoolset.org/) Burn 3.9 to create a bootstrapper (with a custom managed bootstrapper application for the UI).  I'm building a tiny version of the bootstrapper (a couple of megabytes) that downloads dependencies as needed.  I'm also building a version with all dependencies embedded, to support easy installation on secure networks.  The /layout command line option would work for pulling down the dependencies, but my organization prefers a single, monolithic executable to keep things simple for the users.

Everything was going along pretty well until I was asked to add a 1GB virtual appliance file and associated installation readme.  All the bootstrapper has to do is place them in a folder that the user specifies in the bootstrapper UI.  I put the *.ova and *.htm file into a self-extracting zip executable and passed the destination folder to it on the command line.  The web installer version works just fine, but then I tried to build the offline installer, with everything embedded.  I started getting an error from light:

```
light.exe(0,0): error LGHT0306: An error (E_FAIL) was returned while finalizing a CAB file. This most commonly happens when creating a CAB file with more than 65535 files in it. Either reduce the number of files in your installation package or split your installation package's files into more than one CAB file using the Media element.
```

The only relevant-looking conversation about this error that I have found is [here](http://windows-installer-xml-wix-toolset.687559.n2.nabble.com/LGHT0306-Error-less-than-30K-files-td7590143.html).  This seems to be related to file size, not file count.  I'm wondering if the problem is related to the overall size of the bootstrapper executable (which would be about 2 GB) or the size of the very large self-extracting zip executable (about 1 GB).  When I'm building an MSI with WiX, the syntax for breaking things up into separate cab files is pretty clear, but I'm not sure whether the same concepts are exposed for a Burn-based boostrapper, or if it's possible to do much to embed a file of that size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With embedded payloads, Burn uses a .cab file that it attaches to the .exe during the build process. That means there's a 2GB limit on the size of embedded payloads. There might also be a limit on how much you could attach to an .exe.

I haven't tried it but it looks like you can try attaching multiple containers by using explicit [Container elements](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/container.html).

Unless you absolutely need a single .exe, you can also just create an uncompressed bundle. The .msi, .cab, and .exe files would be external but it works if you're creating .iso images for download (for example).

Comment: Thanks, Bob!  I've read [Rob's introduction of containers](http://robmensching.com/blog/posts/2009/7/22/burn-packages-payloads-and-containers/), but I haven't seen an example of explicitly using them.  It sounds like I'm just bumping up against the limits of what can be distributed in a single EXE file, and we might need to make some compromises like zipping the bootstrapper executable with its dependencies or distributing our largest files separately.  Most of our users don't need offline installation, anyway.  Your swift and informative response is much appreciated, as always!

Comment: You can also try high .cab compression. WiX doesn't let you specify compression level for Burn containers but you can override the default level using the WIX_COMPRESSION_LEVEL environment variable. See http://www.joyofsetup.com/2011/06/21/wix-and-cabinetry/.